# MySQL - Average of Unique rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If I have three columns:

```
id, user, points
```

My data is:

```
+-------+------------------+-------------+
|   id  |       user       |  points     |
+-------+------------------+-------------+
|   1   |       A          |    100      |
+-------+------------------+-------------+
|   1   |       A          |    200      |
+-------+------------------+-------------+
|   2   |       B          |    300      |
+-------+------------------+-------------+
|   2   |       B          |    400      |
+-------+------------------+-------------+
```

I would like to have the average of **ONLY** the max points of each user.
For this exmple I want to get as results: 300 points ((200+400)/2).

When I use the following Mysql query, I get: **250**:

```
SELECT avg(points) FROM table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fef3e/2)

Try this :

```
SELECT avg(points) FROM (
    SELECT max(points) as points FROM table1 group by id
) as T
```

Firstly get the `max` points of each user and then get the `AVG` from them.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The solution of @Md. Suman Kabir works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You should first get the max group by use and the the avg of this subquery

```
SELECT AVG(points) 
FROM (SELECT MAX(points) FROM your_table GROUP BY user)  subt
```